# Parse.com & Javascript - Fetching users based on "belongs to" languages

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I need to figure out what the most efficient way is to filter users based on select languages:

I have a users class and a language class.

A user “belongs to” a language, in the sense that the user table has a pointer to the language object.

example:

User class

**objectID**  //  **name**    //       **language**

dxrObFI6Zn  //   Joe Smith   //     pZ8Urxwi8z

…

Language table

**objectID**   //   **iso2**        //     **name**

pZ8Urxwi8z    EN                English

hj3dGlGmNw    ES                Spanish

hj3dGlGmNw    IN                Indonesian

How do I query users that are speak only the language selected by the user?    (Ex: if the user selects english and spanish, only show users that speak english and users that speak spanish)

Thank you so much for your time and looking forward to your response!

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21873950/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-06%20at%203.27.03%20PM.png

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21873950/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-06%20at%203.26.36%20PM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Parse documentation you should do a [relational query](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-relational-queries)

```
var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var Language = Parse.Object.extend("Language");

var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Language);
innerQuery.equalTo("iso2", "EN");
var query = new Parse.Query(User);
query.matchesQuery("language", innerQuery);
query.find({
    success: function(users) {
        ...
        // You have the users with the language object EN.
    }
});
```

For a user speaking english AND spanish so you could do a [query on an array value](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-queries-on-array-values)

```
var Language = Parse.Object.extend("Language");
var queryEN = new Parse.Query(Language);
queryEN.equalTo("iso2", "EN");
var queryES = new Parse.Query(Language);
queryES.equalTo("iso2", "ES");

var languageQuery = Parse.Query.or(queryEN, queryES);
    languageQuery.find({
        success: function(results) {
           var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
           var query = new Parse.Query(User); 
           query.containsAll("language", results);
           query.find({
               success: function(users) {
                   ...
                   // You have the users with the language object EN and ES.
               }
           });
    },
        error: function(error) {
             // There was an error.
    }
});
```

Of course you could fetch and store all your Languages (languageQuery) before doing any requests to avoid fetching them each time you are doing a request on your users languages.

Comment: Thank you! However, what if I want users that speak english AND users that speak spanish?

Comment: sorry but this isn't working for me still: 

could you please type out the full example?  I'll be eternally grateful!!

Comment: @user1683056 what do you need ? What is not working ?

Comment: With the last example, it says query is not defined, so I added this line: 
var query = new Parse.Query(User);    but the error I get is: POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: to be specific, the error says "non supported clause for pointer field language"

Comment: Ok, my example works if you have an array of string with the ID of your objects, I'll see for a solution with an array of object.

Comment: I have updated the example. You shouldn't propose your credentials and put your email ever.

Comment: Hi again - this seems great,  but I'm getting "query is not defined". I tried queryEN.equalsTo and it didn't work. I very much appreciate your help with this

Comment: I have edited the answer sorry for the mistake. What error do you have now ?

Comment: Sorry, typo again, try equalTo.

Comment: that typo is now fixed,  and now I get "non supported clause for pointer field language"  on the User query find

Comment: No problems :-). Can you tell me the type of the language field in your DB ? Is it an array of pointer ?

Comment: I believe it's just a single pointer to a Language object - I attached 2 screenshots to the question. One from the User class and the other from the Language class

Comment: That's why it's not working. You need to put an array of languages.